# Subtract the sum of one column from another table's column

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

What I have tried:

```
SELECT requestformtbl.employee_name, requestformtbl.request_type, requestformtbl.total_day,
                requestformtbl.request_status, requestformtbl.admin_remark, requestformtbl.confirmed_by, requestformtbl.date_confirmed, requesttbl.max_allotment,
                (requesttbl.max_allotment - sum(requestformtbl.total_day)) as Available from requestformtbl inner join requesttbl on 
                requestformtbl.request_type = requesttbl.request_type;
```

error: Column 'requestformtbl.employee_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If requestttbl.request_type="Vacation Leave" has requesttbl.max_allotment=20,
when a new entry in requestformtbl is inserted with requestformtbl.request_type="Vacation Leave" and requestformtbl.total_day=5
I want to get the remaining available leave

Comment: You can't mix aggregate functions like `sum()` with "normal" columns in your select. You need to group your data accordingly. To help you you have to add example data and expected output, preferably simlified.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just updated my question, thank you!

Comment: No. I'm afraid you didn't. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results you want without using a `GROUP BY` by using a correlated subquery to get the sum of the employees used days:

```
SELECT rft.employee_name, 
       rft.request_type, 
       rft.total_day,
       rft.request_status, 
       rft.admin_remark, 
       rft.confirmed_by, 
       rft.date_confirmed, 
       rt.max_allotment,
       rt.max_allotment - (select sum(total_day) 
                           from requestformtbl rft2 
                           where rft2.employee_name = rft.employee_name) as Available
from requestformtbl rft
inner join requesttbl rt on rft.request_type = rt.request_type;
```

Note I've used table aliases to make the query more readable.